# How to call ListClustersResult method to list EKS cluster using AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

we would like to execute the ListClustersResult method to get the list of clusters in specific region.  below is the code snippet from AWS EKS SDK 1.x

URL :

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/5e25da550a536ce727d1f2ecdb13ed5768f4e975/aws-java-sdk-eks/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/eks/AmazonEKSClient.java#L2942

```
 @Override
    public ListClustersResult listClusters(ListClustersRequest request) {
        request = beforeClientExecution(request);
        return executeListClusters(request);
    }
```

how to call this ListClustersResult method in custom java application using maven .
basically, we want to build the java client application which will call this method to list the EKS cluster
Can someone has any sample example ? please suggest